# Opening html file with canvas in WebView javafx

Tags: javascript, canvas, javafx

I'm trying to open score-viewer.html in webView. Code below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/zip.js/arraybuffer.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/zip.js/dataview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/zip.js/deflate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/zip.js/inflate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/zip.js/zip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">zip.workerScriptsPath='../js/zip.js/';</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scorediv-pv0.0.3.js"></script>
<div class="score-div" style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 700px;" musicxml_ref="./musicxml/01a-Pitches-Pitches.xml"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading .html file in JavaFX.

```
WebView webview = null;
WebEngine webEngine = null;
try {

        webview = new WebView();
        webview.setVisible(true);
        webEngine = webview.getEngine();
        webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       final URL urlHello = getClass().getResource("/score-viewer/score-viewer.html");
        webEngine.load(urlHello.toExternalForm());

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        System.err.print("error " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This page should display the tool bar to load notes and the sheet music in the canvas tag,  generated by javascripts. 
If I open the file in Mozilla Firefox, it works, it renders sheet music from .xml file. But in WebView I'm getting only toolbar and black background instead of sheet music.

I've read that the webview should support the canvas tag, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I tried that and got also the black background with the toolbar. When I pressed the refresh button on the toolbar, the sheet was rendered. So it works, but something is preventing the sheet from loading at startup.

This is a hack, but if you load the `score-div` twice, the second one will display correctly:

```
<div class="score-div" musicxml_ref="./musicxml/01a-Pitches-Pitches.xml"></div>
<div class="score-div" style="position: relative; width: 700px; height: 500px;" musicxml_ref="./musicxml/01a-Pitches-Pitches.xml"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave up the use of this solution in my application. I'm going to use [Zong!](https://xenoage.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ZONG/Develop). Did you open the sheet music from java GUI or javascript GUI? I was curious how to do it by java.

Comment: From Java GUI, using mostly the same code that you posted.